# List with 'can only view his own item' and item approval do not work with Approver permission

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

Simple list with approval feature. Members are set that they can only view and edit their own. I have also one set of approvers that should approve. However the approvers do not see the items. I have to upgrade them to designer to let them see the things they need to approve.

Is this normal?

When I tick 'who can see items' as 'approvers and the item creator' I supposed that the permission profile called 'approver' would be enough. Instead I need Designer or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is normal, users need the Manage List permissions, which is included in Design. The list settings specifies this:

> Note: Users with the Manage Lists permission can read and edit all
>   items.

You could edit the Approver permission to include this if you wanted. Site Settings, Site Permissions, Permission Levels, click Approver and tick the box for Manage Lists and click OK.